# Flutter Simulator-Choice Button gone in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

Very silly question but one that I kept spending my sweet time already:

How do I get back the simulator-choice-button inside my VSCode StatusBar (blue bottom bar).

I don't know what unwantedly pressed shortcut made it go away.

It used to sit here (see red box in picture below), next to the feedback-smiley.

There used to be a button that opened an extra window where I was able to choose my simulator or emulators. But that button is gone for some reason, even tough I have open simulators and emulators available.

BUT NOW THE BUTTON IS GONE. HOW DO I GET IT BACK ??????

Also, I used to be able to press F5 to run the project. But that does now work anymore either !

Instead, I can only run my flutter project from within VSCode when I type "flutter run" into my VSCode-terminal. What is wrong here ?

If I press F5, it just shows me the following error message:

```
lib/main.dart:1: Warning: Interpreting this as package URI, 'package:chunder/main.dart'.
file:///Users/myusername/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui show Paint, Path, Canvas;
       ^
file:///Users/myusername/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:10:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
file:///Users/myusername/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
file:///Users/myusername/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/colors.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show Color;
       ^
file:///Users/myusername/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui';
       ^
file:///Users/myusername/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_border.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
file:///Users/myusername/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
file:///Users/myusername/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/mergeable_material.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
file:///Users/myusername/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/shadows.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show Color, Offset;
       ^
file:///Users/myusername/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/slider_theme.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show Path;
```

Any help appreciated !

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to download again the packages with: `flutter packages get` and if you run `flutter doctor` do you get any error?

Comment: yes, I did. Packages downloaded correctly and flutter doctor all green (recognising open simulator and emulator)... Running the flutter project with `flutter run` also works. But I do completely miss why VSCode can no longer run my flutter project.

Comment: And did you try reinstalling the flutter plugin?

Comment: you mean all of them ?? (my projects have several). In fact the problem somehow started playing a role once I moved my flutter projects to a subfolder... But changing that back did not help any.

Comment: No! O_O I mean the vscode flutter and dart plugins (the extensions). ^^ I would try also to create a minimal brand new test project and run it all from command line.

Comment: Wait, the stuff of moving the project seems a cache corrupted. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#pub-dependencies).

Comment: Hmm, could be and is very annoying if it is the case. The workarounds do not seem to work. I don't know how to run `pub cache repair`. it just sais command not found. Where do I run `pub cache repair` ?? do you have any idea ?

Comment: I have > 30 flutter projects in my folder and subfolder structure. Could it be a question of time until VSCode caches the stuff (or does things in the background). Maybe I just have to wait.... What do you think ?  (...I come up with this because slowly but surely the red file and folder-names turn white inside VSCode - so there must something going on under the hoods....)

Comment: Well it’s in the flutter root project in a bin folder. You can type ‘where flutter’ to see the <root flutter project folder>/bin/flutter. But it’s not in the same bin of flutter command. But if you search inside the root you will find it (I’m on mobile right now). Btw try first the brand new project test.

Comment: `where flutter` does not work in my terminal

Comment: You are on windows right?

Comment: no mac :)  - aaaahhh: I have a solution:  I just deleted the 30 flutter projects and re-arranged the old folder structure. And now my simulators and emulators (with its button in VSCode) can be found again !

Comment: I completely miss the point what VSCode does under the hood here. With one or two flutter projects in a folder, then VSCode works well. But with more projects it gets completely messed up (or I was not patient enough to wait > 2hours until its done with its caching...

Comment: Okay gr8. Glad to know anyway we found a solution. [-;  so in linux/mac (just to know) the command is ‘which flutter’

Comment: great - thank you very much. I will try another time with more files and folder. And maybe go with the workaround that was proposed. For now, I am just happy that F5 and simulator-choice works again...

Answer (score 2):

The text "Dart from Flutter" in the status bar shows when the project you open is not detected as as Flutter project (but rather just a standard Dart project), but the Dart SDK being used is the one embedded in the Flutter SDK.

The usual causes for this are that the folder you've opened in VS Code is not a Flutter project itself (for example, maybe you opened the parent folder, and the Flutter project is in a sub-folder).

This has been made better in recent releases (we'll look inside the first level of children), but if you're still seeing it, please open an issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code) and we can try to improve it further. Thanks!

Comment: thanks Danny, I solved it (there was something wrong with my VSCode workspaces). After creating new workspaces and dragging-dropping each and every project in there, everything was fine again... (I have no idea why it go corrupted in the first place - maybe it was as you mentioned with a non-Flutter project hidden somewhere... )...

Comment: Having a non-Flutter project shouldn't break things - we go into "Flutter mode" if we detect *any* Flutter projects in the workspace (since we can only have one analyzer for the whole workspace). Anyway, if you see it again, please do open an issue or ping me on Gitter/Twitter (@DanTup) and we can figure it out :-)